# Execute if block not working properly

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I was working on a command block setup for night vision, strength, enchanted swords, and such on Bedrock Edition, specifically on a iPad, since typing commands is slow without a working tab key. Since swords can have different enchantments (smite, sharpness, bane of arthropods, knockback, no knockback, fire aspect, no fire aspect…), I set up three lines of command blocks for the damage modifiers, (sharpness smite and bane), but wanted a lever for fire aspect and knockback. The levers were too close together for comparators and redstone torches to not power the wrong blocks, so I tried `execute if block [xyz] lever 1` and it would output “Test passed.” if the lever was down, and “Execute subcommand if block test failed” if it was up, but `execute if block [xyz] lever 0` outputted “Execute subcommand if block test failed” as up or down.

Am I using the wrong command/data value, or is it not working properly?

Comment: What else did you expect?

Comment: execute if block [xyz] lever 0 should pass if the lever is down, shouldn’t it?

Comment: No, the default state is the inactive one. The wiki tells you all the block states in each block's article.